# how to do dashed line threshold using Amchart?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, frontend, amcharts

This is the threshold that I am using:

[image: the threshold]

and this is the graph:

```
const graphHighs = {
  pk: series.pk,
  lineColor: series.seriesMetaData.colorHex,
  lineThickness: series.graph.thickness,
  valueField: `${series.pk.uuid}${series.seriesMetaData.reportType}-highs`,
  valueAxis: series.seriesMetaData.unitOfMeasurement,
  lineAlpha: series.graph.opacity,
  type: "line"
};

const graphLows = {
  pk: series.pk,
  lineColor: series.seriesMetaData.colorHex,
  valueAxis: series.seriesMetaData.unitOfMeasurement,
  lineThickness: series.graph.thickness,
  valueField: `${series.pk.uuid}${series.seriesMetaData.reportType}-lows`,
  lineAlpha: series.graph.opacity,
  type: "line"
};
```

I need to change the line to dotted line (dashed line) 
thanks
 this is the link for the image: [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CJMjX.png)

Comment: Which version of amcharts are you using ? Do you have an example of your "series" object ?

Comment: I am using amcharts 3

Comment: i found the answer thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

need to add dashLength: 14.

```
const graphHighs = {
    pk: series.pk,
    lineColor: series.seriesMetaData.colorHex,
    lineThickness: series.graph.thickness,
    valueField: `${series.pk.uuid}${series.seriesMetaData.reportType}-highs`,
    valueAxis: series.seriesMetaData.unitOfMeasurement,
    lineAlpha: series.graph.opacity,
    **dashLength: 14,**
    type: 'line',
   }
const graphLows = {
     pk: series.pk,
     lineColor: series.seriesMetaData.colorHex,
     valueAxis: series.seriesMetaData.unitOfMeasurement,
     lineThickness: series.graph.thickness,
     valueField: `${series.pk.uuid}${series.seriesMetaData.reportType}-lows`,
     lineAlpha: series.graph.opacity,
     **dashLength: 14,**
     type: "line"
    };
```